# Maven - How to override version?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, gmaven

my pom.xml looks like this:

```
<project>
...
<version>1.0.0-A</version>
...
</project>
```

I have to get rid of the '-A' suffix. So I found this plugin which removes it and saves it into a new variable.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <source>
                System.setProperty("versionWithOutPrefix", "${project.version}".replace('-SNAPSHOT', ''))
              </source>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

But I need to get the value of `<version>` changed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Looks like you're going at this the very wrong way. First, why do you have `1.0.0-A`? What does it mean? Is it a snapshot? An alpha? Then you can release your project with maven-release-plugin and change the version... Or if you want to _just_ change the version without releasing, use `versions:set` of http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes it's a snapshot. The plan is that the developer should be able to define it as a snapshot but the value of <version> in the lifecycle generate-sources shouldn't be a snapshot just 1.0.0.

Comment: Why do you want to change the version during the build?

Comment: Because it should be only one step for the developer. Building it and while the building the version should be already be the correct one.

Comment: the versions plugin is often used to shorten the maven release cycle or ease the handling of replacing version numbers: http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/